# How do I cast Service Descriptor to DbContext class in .NET Core 6 program class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a `DbContext` class. I have registered that class using this method in my `program.cs` file:

```
using BethanyPieShop.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Register depancies for data acess it is good to use add scoped
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPieRespository, MockPieRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICatgeoryRepository, MockCategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPieRespository, PieRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICatgeoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseHsts();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

// this important:
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Pie}/{action=List}/{id?}");

var serviceDescriptor = builder.Services.Where(sd => sd.ServiceType.Name.Contains("AppDbContext")).FirstOrDefault();
serviceDescriptor.ServiceType.GetType().

// AppDbContext context = (AppDbContext)builder.Services[0];
DbInitializer.Seed((AppDbContext)serviceDescriptor);
app.Run();
```

Now I have another static class that is asking for the `DbContext`.

Here is my class:

```
namespace BethanyPieShop.Models
{
    public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Seed(AppDbContext context)
        {
            //AppDbContext context = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

            if (!context.Categories.Any())
            {
                context.Categories.AddRange(Categories.Select(c => c.Value));
            }

            if (!context.Pies.Any())
            {
                context.AddRange
                (
                    new Pie { Name = "Apple Pie", Price = 12.95M, ShortDescription = "Our famous apple pies!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Fruit pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/applepie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = true, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/applepiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Blueberry Cheese Cake", Price = 18.95M, ShortDescription = "You'll love it!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Cheese cakes"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/blueberrycheesecake.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/blueberrycheesecakesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Cheese Cake", Price = 18.95M, ShortDescription = "Plain cheese cake. Plain pleasure.", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Cheese cakes"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cheesecake.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cheesecakesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Cherry Pie", Price = 15.95M, ShortDescription = "A summer classic!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Fruit pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cherrypie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cherrypiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Christmas Apple Pie", Price = 13.95M, ShortDescription = "Happy holidays with this pie!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Seasonal pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/christmasapplepie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/christmasapplepiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Cranberry Pie", Price = 17.95M, ShortDescription = "A Christmas favorite", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Seasonal pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cranberrypie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/cranberrypiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Peach Pie", Price = 15.95M, ShortDescription = "Sweet as peach", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Fruit pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/peachpie.jpg", InStock = false, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/peachpiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Pumpkin Pie", Price = 12.95M, ShortDescription = "Our Halloween favorite", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Seasonal pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/pumpkinpie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = true, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/pumpkinpiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Rhubarb Pie", Price = 15.95M, ShortDescription = "My God, so sweet!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Fruit pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/rhubarbpie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = true, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/rhubarbpiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Strawberry Pie", Price = 15.95M, ShortDescription = "Our delicious strawberry pie!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Fruit pies"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/strawberrypie.jpg", InStock = true, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/strawberrypiesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" },
                    new Pie { Name = "Strawberry Cheese Cake", Price = 18.95M, ShortDescription = "You'll love it!", LongDescription = "Icing carrot cake jelly-o cheesecake. Sweet roll marzipan marshmallow toffee brownie brownie candy tootsie roll. Chocolate cake gingerbread tootsie roll oat cake pie chocolate bar cookie dragée brownie. Lollipop cotton candy cake bear claw oat cake. Dragée candy canes dessert tart. Marzipan dragée gummies lollipop jujubes chocolate bar candy canes. Icing gingerbread chupa chups cotton candy cookie sweet icing bonbon gummies. Gummies lollipop brownie biscuit danish chocolate cake. Danish powder cookie macaroon chocolate donut tart. Carrot cake dragée croissant lemon drops liquorice lemon drops cookie lollipop toffee. Carrot cake carrot cake liquorice sugar plum topping bonbon pie muffin jujubes. Jelly pastry wafer tart caramels bear claw. Tiramisu tart pie cake danish lemon drops. Brownie cupcake dragée gummies.", Category = Categories["Cheese cakes"], ImageUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/strawberrycheesecake.jpg", InStock = false, IsPieOfTheWeek = false, ImageThumbnailUrl = "https://gillcleerenpluralsight.blob.core.windows.net/files/strawberrycheesecakesmall.jpg", AllergyInformation = "" }
                );
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, Category> categories;

        public static Dictionary<string, Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                if (categories == null)
                {
                    var genresList = new Category[]
                    {
                        new Category { CategoryName = "Fruit pies" },
                        new Category { CategoryName = "Cheese cakes" },
                        new Category { CategoryName = "Seasonal pies" }
                    };

                    categories = new Dictionary<string, Category>();

                    foreach (Category genre in genresList)
                    {
                        categories.Add(genre.CategoryName, genre);
                    }
                }

                return categories;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my program class, I am calling

```
DbInitializer.Seed((AppDbContext)serviceDescriptor);
```

If I search all my registered services in the builder.

I can find the service descriptor for the `DbContext` class:

```
var serviceDescriptor = builder.Services.Where(sd => sd.ServiceType.Name.Contains("AppDbContext")).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I cast the `serviceDescriptor` to `AppDbContext`?

I know I can solve the problem by using a startup class and in the `CreateHost` method I can get the context from the Host. I need other solution please.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have missed something,  why are you trying to manually call the `Seed` method like this?

Comment: I am trying a new way instead of modelcreating event in dbcointext

Comment: `Seed` is generally reserved for schema updates, you only need to seed when the data structure has changed, so _Seed_ is generally outside of your application runtime. Unless you are using an InMemoryDbContext, then it makes some sense, but I would do that differently.

Comment: I understand. I am doing it only once as I am checking if records are exist. Any ways I got it working usingv ar scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

Comment: I see the answer, I just don't want future readers to find this post and think it is the expected way to deal with this situation. You really shouldn't be calling Seed directly at all.

Comment: Your question is not about casting at all, but how to resolve or access the DbContext from the ServiceDescriptor.

Comment: if you want I can close the question @ChrisSchaller

Comment: I put the call out there, I was really just trying to encourage an "ah huh" moment, why are you unhappy with the standard implementation of the `Seed` method, where it is called during the `update-database` command, after the migration is applied (if there is one pending). You can call `update-database` at any time, if there is no migration, it will simply call `Seed`. I just don't see why you are trying to achieve here or what the value might be.

Comment: I am doing it only once per appolication life time, that is why I configure it here

Comment: Yeah but that is once per application schema lifetime, once only ever, that is why `Seed` is called from the `update-database` command, You don't need that logic executing every time your app starts up a new instance.

Comment: i will change the question on how to access dbcontext in program.cs file ? @ChrisSchaller

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved it using

```
var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
```

now ctx holds my context data.